# Exclusão Lógica PHP

Tags: php

Estou iniciando os meus estudos em PHP. Preciso fazer uma exclusão lógica e embora já tenha achado bastante conteúdo sobre o tema, não encontro como exatamente fazer a exclusão lógica em PHP. A minha eu fiz assim (física):

```
function remove( $table = null, $id = null ) {
  $database = open_database();

  try {
    if ($id) {
      $sql = "DELETE FROM " . $table . " WHERE id = " . $id;
      $result = $database->query($sql);
      if ($result = $database->query($sql)) {       
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Registro Removido com Sucesso.";
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) { 
    $_SESSION['message'] = $e->GetMessage();
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
  }
```

Até agora entendi que preciso colocar a data da exclusão e apenas editar ao invés de deletar, mas não entendi realmente como funciona Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exclusão lógica** é uma prática para evitar a perda de dados. Ao invés de apagar o registro do banco, você sinaliza em um campo que aquele registro está excluído.

Uma coisa a ser considerada é que o PHP em si não altera o banco de dados, ele apenas envia comandos SQL em forma de string para que o SGBD execute.

**Exemplo**

Você pode criar uma coluna "**deletado**" do tipo timestamp. Ao invés de apagar o registro, apenas atualize essa coluna com o timestamp atual.

Veja o exemplo em PHP/MySQL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET deletado=NOW() WHERE id = $id";
```

Esse comando irá atualizar o campo 'deletado' do registro com um timestamp.
A função NOW() do MySQL retorna um timestamp automaticamente.

A partir disso, você vai selecionar apenas os registros que tiverem o campo deletado nulo. Esses serão os registros "ativos". Exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE deletado IS NULL";
```

Quando você quiser retornar os registros deletados logicamente, faça uma query para selecionar apenas os registros onde o campo deletado não é nulo, por exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE deletado IS NOT NULL";
```

Para "reativar" um registro, atualize o campo deletado para NULL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET deletado = NULL WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: Obrigada, Igor. Agora me esclareceu o suficiente para eu tentar implementar.